# Create an unordered list from unknown JSON content in C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json

I am looking to create a treeview style field selector similar to http://json.parser.online.fr/.

The idea being that the user can select which fields they want to use from an unknown source of JSON content.

I want to create an output similar to http://mind2soft.com/labs/jquery/tree/ but creating the content in C#

I have the following code

```
JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(jsoncontent));
string output = @"<ul id='tree'>
                <li><a href='#'>Data Preview</a>
                <ul>";
while (reader.Read()) {
    if (reader.Value != null) {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.PropertyName) {
            output += "<li><a href=''>" + reader.Value.ToString() + "</a></li>";
        }

    } else {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray) {
            output += "<ul><li>";
        }
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.EndArray) {
            output += "</li></ul>";
        }
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject) {
            output += "<ul>";
        }
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.EndObject) {
            output += "</ul>";
        }
    }
}

output += @"</ul>
            </li>
            </ul>";
```

However my desired output is creating multiple of 'UL' tags as I am starting arrays and objects at the same time.

Can anyone please guide me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: seems to me like this would be easier to do client-side working directly with the json object with jQuery to assist with DOM manipulations, might just be me though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the `if` inside the `else` condition with `if else` statements

```
if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray) {
    output += "<ul><li>";
}
else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.EndArray) {
    output += "</li></ul>";
}
else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject) {
    output += "<ul>";
}
else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.EndObject) {
    output += "</ul>";
}
```

Looks like multiple conditions are being satisfied on each iteration